# jquery disable custom function applied to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function assigned to an element (an input). It works but once it's applied I can not disable it

```
 function applyCustomfunc() {
      $('#element').customFunction();
 }
```

I need to write another function which will be triggered onclick and will disable the first one

```
 function disableCustomfunc () {
     /// Do something
 }
```

Comment: Add a `destroy()` method to your `customFunction()` logic which removes any data and events you added to the element. Without know what your jQuery extension does, we can't really help you.

Comment: Show us your plugin code.

Comment: As @RoryMcCrossan said, give us more info: when and how `applyCustomfunc()` is triggered? Why do you need to disable your custom function?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the css `pointerEvents` property to disable or enable clicking of any element see demo

```js
$("#click-element").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("clicked");
});

$("#disable").on('click', function() {
  $("#click-element").css({
    pointerEvents: 'none'
  });
})

$("#enable").on('click', function() {
  $("#click-element").css({
    pointerEvents: 'auto'
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">


<a href="#." id="click-element">Click it <i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
<div>
  <input type="button" value="Disable Now" id="disable">
  <input type="button" value="Enable Now" id="enable">
</div>
```

For Your case you can use it like

To disable the customFunction

```
function disableCustomfunc () {
     $("#element").css({pointerEvents:'none'});
 }
```

Enable it back using

```
 function enableCustomfunc () {
     $("#element").css({pointerEvents:'auto'});
 }
```